# Can I convert List<V> to Map<K, List<V>> without foreach?

Tags: java

I have list of objects. Each object has property "date" and I need to convert this List to Map where key is "date" and value is List of objects.

I can do this by using standard foreach, but is it possible to do this with Java 8 and streams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what [`collect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) with [`groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) is for :

```
Map<K, List<V>> groups = listOfVs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(V::getK));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Stream` API with Java 8 to group the items in the `List` by date and place them in a `Map` like so:

```
Map<Date, List<YourObject>> collisions = yourObjectsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YourObject::getDate));
```